# Newbie Django blog with Mysql Following the Official Django Blog App Tutorial Need

Tags: mysql, django, vps

I am following along with the official django blog tutorial. 
I have my own Vps Server that I pay for.
I see most tutorials are showing if the developer is doing it on a home `localhost` system. I do know I have Mysql on my hosting account.
I am trying to use Mysql but soon as I add Mysql info  like

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'urbanpyt_polls',
    'USER': 'urbanpyt_dbz',
    'PASSWORD': 'shawn316566613'
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'port': '',
}
```

}

after putting this in my settings.py the virtual environment won't even load anymore. I don't know what to do. Every tutorial I watch is showing on a home server. not a Vps with Mysql already installed. 
I hope someone can help me. 
I may delete and try all over again. since I'm new I know I might have something wrong. 
The only leads I've gotten is that people are saying don't use mysql to use the default. my only concern if I tried it this way will the default be really installed on the server or will it be virtual like running the virtual environment.

Comment: You didn't mention which blog you following.

Comment: arent you able to do `source bin/activate` what do you mean by "virtual environment won't even load anymore"?

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to enable virtual environment ?

Comment: Pro Tip: Never share your password online.